# Need help with this function growth proof

Tags: proof-writing, asymptotics

Prove that:

$\forall b \in \mathbb{R}, \forall c, n_0 \in \mathbb{N^+}, \exists n \in \mathbb{N^+} \text{ s.t. } n \geqslant n_0 \text{ AND } bn^2 < c2^n  $.

I tried an Epsilon-Delta style proof and didn't get anywhere. Perhaps I did it wrong?

I have tried proof by contradiction and didn't was not sure what to set $n_0$ to.
Anyone have any ideas on how to do this one?

Comment: Please clarify $n \geqslant n_0 \land bn^2 < c2^n$. You have inequalities facing different direct, and I am not sure what you are using $\land$ to represent. Also, please include any relevant ideas you have tried.

Comment: What inequalities facing different directions do you mean? The $\land$ is just "AND". So we are trying to prove that $n \geqslant n_0 \land bn^2 < c2^n$.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to show that the sequence $(\frac{n^2}{2^n})$ is a null sequence. But this follows from $2^n=(1+1)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}>\binom{n}3$ for $n\geq3$.

Comment: But what about the coefficients $b$ and $c$.

Comment: If the sequence $ (\frac{n^2}{2^n}) $ is a null sequence, $\frac{n^2}{2^n}<\frac{c}{b}$ for all sufficiently large $n$.